# MySql Show values not in the second table

Tags: mysql, join, intersection

I am trying to offer tickets for other events to people who have booked for one event.  I have two tables like

```
---Concerts----------------
|  ConcertID  | Concert   |
---------------------------
|   101       | Mozart    |
|   102       | Beethoven |
|   103       | Chopin    |
---------------------------

---Tickets--------------------------------------------
| TicketNum |  Name      |  email       | ConcertID  | 
------------------------------------------------------
| 5001      | Amy Jones  | aaa@aaa.com  |  101       |
| 5002      | Amy Jones  | aaa@aaa.com  |  102       |
| 5003      | John Doe   | bbb@bbb.com  |  102       |
| 5004      | Adam Smith | ccc@ccc.com  |  101       |
| 5005      | Jerry Coe  | ddd@ddd.com  |  102       |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to construct a statement like

```
SELECT Tickets.email, Concerts.ConcertID, Concerts.Concert FROM Tickets, Concerts 
WHERE (Show Concerts Not Booked)
AND Concerts.ConcertID = Tickets.ConcertID 
AND email = "bbb.com"
```

This show then return the two concerts that John Doe is not booked on to i.e. 101 Mozart and 102 Chopin.

It's the (Show Concerts Not Booked) that I am struggling with

I can construct a query to show the intersection of which concerts he is booked on to, but I cannot show the ones that he is not booked on to.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select c.ConcertID, C.Concert
From Concerts c
Left join Tickets t On t.ConcertID = c.ConcertID
Where t.ConcertID is null and t.Name = 'John Doe'
```

Would do that.

Without the aliases might make what is going on clearer

```
Select Concerts.ConcertID, Concerts.Concert
From Concerts
Left join Tickets On Tickets.ConcertID = Concerts.ConcertID
Where Tickets.ConcertID is null and Tickets.Name = 'John Doe'
```

Think of it this way, if you wanted a list of all the concerts and whether John had bought a ticket
you would do

```
Select *
From Concerts
Left join Tickets On Tickets.ConcertID = Concerts.ConcertID
Where Tickets.Name = 'John Doe'
```

and get

```
101 Mozart    NULL  NULL    NULL        NULL 
102 Beethoven 5003 John Doe bbb@bbb.com 102
103 Chopin    NULL NULL     NULL        NULL
```

so the extra condition in the where statement filters out the rows where no ticket exists.

Well that was irritating, after playing about with @JungSu Heo's sql fiddle, I found this worked

```
Select *
From Concerts c
Left join Tickets t On t.ConcertID = c.ConcertID and t.Name = 'John Doe'
Where t.ConcertID is null
```

Makes sense after a bit of thought, because John Doe was in where clause the nulls were being chopped out. Do it in the join clause, then John Doe is only used to constrain the outer join.

Thank you learnt something, though I wouldn't normally see something like this because I'd have had a names/bookers type table.

Comment: Tried that (Changing C to Concerts) but got error message of - MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: I have tried this - SELECT Concerts.ConcertID, Concerts.Concert
FROM Concerts
LEFT JOIN Tickets t ON t.ConcertID = Concerts.ConcertID
WHERE Concerts.ConcertID IS NULL
AND t.Name = 'John Doe'
LIMIT 0 , 30 - but I get an empty result

Comment: oops, hold on missed the alias out. You attempt failed because you looked for all tickets booked to non-existent concerts...

Comment: I have used this to show the concerts that John Doe is booked on to - Select c.ConcertID, c.Concert
From Concerts c
Left join Tickets t On t.ConcertID = c.ConcertID
Where  t.Name = 'John Doe'  - but cannot get the ones he is not booked on to

Comment: Now I'm puzzled, that query should have returned all the concerts

Comment: Tried - SELECT *
FROM Concerts
LEFT JOIN Tickets ON Tickets.ConcertID = Concerts.ConcertID
WHERE Tickets.Name = 'John Doe'
LIMIT 0 , 30 but only get one row.  I have pasted the tables in the answer below

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Tony, here is sqlfiddle with OP's data. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fd32/2/0 I could not follow up any more. It's 8 pm saturday. I'm working at office. It's time to go home.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand why Tony's query is not working. could you try this?

```
SELECT c.ConcertID, c.Concert
FROM Concerts c
WHERE c.ConcertID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT ConcertID
    FROM Tickets
    WHERE Name = 'John Doe'
)
```

If you post you data at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/, we would appreciate you. easy to test.

Comment: Ton'y query wasn't working becsause he's a twit and missed the alias out. :) Yours will work, I always go straight for the left join as sometimes DBMS's make a pigs ear of this form and end up with something that doesn't perform as well.

Comment: Thanks Tony!. and @user3051841, tony's is better than mine. I just want to check your data, there is really 101 and 103 tickets Doe has not booked using strait forward 'NOT IN' (easy to understand, but In MySQL this is little bit slow)

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Concerts` (
  `ConcertID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Concert` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


Concerts data - INSERT INTO `Concerts` (`ConcertID`, `Concert`) VALUES
(101, 'Mozart'),
(102, 'Beethoven'),
(103, 'Chopin');

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tickets` (
  `TicketNum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ConcertID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Tickets` (`TicketNum`, `Name`, `email`, `ConcertID`) VALUES
(5001, 'Amy Jones', 'aaa@aaa.com', 101),
(5002, 'Amy Jones', 'aaa@aaa.com', 102),
(5003, 'John Doe', 'bbb@bbb.com', 102);

Comment: @user3051841 wait a minute. I'm checking.

Comment: @user3051841 Thanks, My original query has typo. what MySQL client program do you use? I guess, when getting error, the client don't show error message, just produces empty result. Turning on error message report would be better (I' not sure just guess. and I didn't check this comments English grammar, spelling. sorry for my bad English)